# how to print array elements in column

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am reading names from text file exnames.txt

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd
bbb kkk zzz fff
```

code is here ,

```
try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("XML/exnames.txt"));
            while (true) {          
                String line = br.readLine();                
                if (line == null) 
                    break;
            //  System.out.println(line);
                String[] data = line.split("\t");   
                for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                    System.out.println(data[i] + data[i+1]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error "+e);
        }
```

and I want to print it in following order

```
aaa bbb
aaa ccc
aaa ddd
bbb kkk
bbb zzz
bbb fff
```

repeating the first element and loop thru second element onwards
pls help if i user array[i]+array[i+1] its giving indexbound exception..

Comment: Read the error, it's pretty self explanatory. Loop to `data.length - 1` because accessing `i + 1` may cause it to access outside of array's bounds.

Comment: if you say i<data.length-1 does it go better?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be what they're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the first element of `data` on each line, plus the current element, try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { // loop starting on 1 (the second element)
    System.out.println(data[0]+" "+data[i]); // first element + space + current element
}
```

This would print, conceptually:

```
data[0] data[1]
data[0] data[2]
data[0] data[3]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

//Loop through your list

```
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(data[i-1]+" "+data[i]); 
// first and second element is printed
    System.out.println(data[i-1]+" "+data[i+1]); 
// first and third element is printed
    System.out.println(data[i-1]+" "+data[i+2]); 
// first and fourth element is printed
}
```